# Why is .ToLocalTime not converting UTC time to local time?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I have code in my razor view:

```
@Model.DateUpdated.ToLocalTime().ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

In my model the property is as follows:

```
public DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
```

This is populated from a date stored in the database as a UTC DateTime.

So when the time in the database comes back as 01/01/2018 08:00, I expect it to render in the view as 01/01/2018 09:00 as my local time (the machine I'm running this on) is UTC+1.

However, it remains as it's original time, retrieved from the database.

How can I get it to convert to the time zone of the server the application is running on?

Comment: Is the local time on the web server the same as your local time?

Comment: ToLocalTime() in that context will be the local time of the web server, not the browser accessing the server.

Comment: I've mentioned in my question that I'm running it on my machine (as well as browsing to it on my machine.) Localhost. I want to get it working there first :)

Comment: Have a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/choosing-between-datetime#the-datetimeoffset-structure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you output the string I'd suggest logging the `DateTimeKind` of the `DateUpdated` field.

e.g.

```
Console.WriteLine(DateUpdated.Kind);
```

To ensure the field DateUpdated is actually UTC you can try:

```
DateUpdated = new DateTime(DateUpdated.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

Then when you output, the result should actually be in local time.

If the DateTimeKind of the original DateUpdated field was DateTimeKind.Local, the function .ToLocalTime() will have no effect. This can happen when you load a DateTime from an external source, e.g. Database, parsing etc.

If the .Kind property of the DateUpdated field was either UTC or Unspecified, the ToLocalTime() call should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks. Any way to get my db DateTime fields to originate with UTC DateTimeKind?

Comment: I'd suggest just hooking in to the function that loads the date from the database. I think the issue is that db dates don't usually contain the time zone.

Comment: I got it working locally, but when deployed to Azure it's rendering the time in UTC again -_-

Comment: Is it possible the server timezone is UTC?

Comment: It would appear obe that, yes. I used the WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE app setting to specify my time zone (GMT) which has got it all working however I'm told this is not best practice in Azure and is only intended to support legacy systems. So I'm still unsure as to what the correct way to do it is. I'll start another question.

Comment: @egmfrs, did you get this figured out? If so, can you post the answer or a link to your new question?

Comment: @JonCrowell actually, I didn't, but coincidentally we were discussing it in a team meeting on Tuesday. I think the general consensus is to use javascript to find the timezone of the current users machine and then format the UTC time on the client side.

Comment: @JonCrowell try appending 'UTC' to the string before converting it to a date in javascript: `var date = new Date('9/14/2018 5:00:00 PM UTC');` then use `date.ToString();` which should render the date and time as local version.

Comment: Thanks, @egmfrs. I ended up doing the conversion on the client with javascript as well.